# Is there a free (non-trial) version of Memurai available?

Tags: memurai

I'm just evaluating databases for one of our products and found RedisDb. Unfortunately this does not seem to be supported for windows and the current best option seems to be Memurai.

On their webpage I see that you can download a free 10 days evaluation version.

Is there a free version available like for other dbs (e.g. mongodb) or does someone now how much they charge for using this in an commercial product?

Answer (score 3):

Memurai Developer is free to download and it is intended for explorations and development only, it is not intended for production use. After 10 days it will stop, however, a simple restart will make it run for another 10 days. There are no time-bombs, or restrictions on how many times Memurai Developer can be restarted.
Memurai Enterprise is designed for production use; the pricing is dependent on the use-cases. For more details please contact the Memurai team https://www.memurai.com/contact

Comment: If anyone may wonder whether the free edition CAN be used in production, the answer seems "no". The memura site uses phrases about the free version that are not so definitive (like how it's "intended" for development use), and some may wonder (like I did) whether there was specific PROHIBITION of production use. I could not find it in the site or the the terms offered on the site (memurai.com/terms). But once you install it, the file Memurai-Developer-EULA.rtf does say clearly, "You may not use the software in a production environment."

Comment: I can confirm that this statement (prohibiting prod use) is still in the EULA (of the same filename) for the current (as I write) 4.0.1 .msi installer of Memurai Developer edition. I suppose some may argue that if it's that hard to find the prohibition, perhaps it's ok to proceed using the Dev edition for prod use (if it's of a nature that the limitations are acceptable). I just try to help people find info. Would be nice if we heard a formal reply from the Memurai folks. (It's not clear if @Rushvel was answering that way.)

Answer (score 0):

"Hello,

I’m a member of the Memurai team and I want to add some information to this discussion. The developer edition of Memurai is free for use in a development environment indefinitely. However, it will stop working every 10 days and require a restart. Apart from that, it has the same features as the Enterprise edition.

Using the developer edition in production in not allowed for any version of Memurai as stated [here](https://www.memurai.com/get-memurai). If you are interested in the pricing of the Enterprise edition, please [contact](https://www.memurai.com/contact) the team for a quote.

Thank you!